# How do you get the value of an async operation inside a non-async function?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

So I have this Widget that display stock prices. I use an HTTP call to get stock prices and of course this function is async and in the body I await the network service to finish before returning the stock price. However every time I try to print this stockPrice it says it's a future but I don't get how to unwrap it? I already have await in my network call so shouldn't that unwrap it and give me the real value behind?

```
StockService stockService = new StockService();
           var stockPrice = stockService.getStockPriceBySymbol(symbols.elementAt(x));
           print(stockPrice);
```

NetworkServices:

```
Future<dynamic> getStockPriceBySymbol(String symbol) async {
    NetworkService networkService = NetworkService(
        '$alphaStockApiURL?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=$symbol&apikey=$kAlphaStockAPIKey');

    var stockData = await networkService.getData();
    // print(stockData['Global Quote']['05. price']);
    return stockData['Global Quote']['05. price'];
  }
```

Comment: `getStockPriceBySymbol()` also returns `Future`, so you need to `await` it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a await stockService.getStockPriceBySymbol

```
var stockPrice = await stockService.getStockPriceBySymbol(symbols.elementAt(x));
```

or a future .then

```
stockService.getStockPriceBySymbol(symbols.elementAt(x)).then((stockPrice){
  print(stockPrice);
)};
```

Comment: But then I can't call this code in my Widget because the Widget can't be type async. I moved my code to a new async method but won't that method just create another Future? I guess I have to use the future inside this method somehow update my UI

Comment: yes you can create another future, where you call it in the initstate one time, or each time when the widget build... with a futurebuilder()